# How to search for the object of a foreign key django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating an Task Completion Queue where people create Projects then add Posts to that specific Project, kind of like comments on a blog post. I am creating a detail view for the Project model, and I want to search all of the posts using the Project as a parameter because I only want posts that pertain to that specific Project. The problem is I cant figure out how to use the model currently being used as a search parameter in a Detail view

Here's my models.py

```
class MyProjects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(MyProjects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```

And here is my views.py

```
class ProjectView(DetailView):
    model = MyProjects


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        CurrentProject = get_object_or_404(MyProjects, title=self.kwargs['MyProjects'])
        completed = Post.objects.filter(status='Completed', project= CurrentProject)
        inProgress = Post.objects.filter(status='InProgress', project= CurrentProject)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(project= CurrentProject)
        Features = Post.objects.filter(ticket_type='Features', project= CurrentProject)

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts '] = posts 
        context['Features '] = Features 
        context['completed '] = completed 
        context['inProgress '] = inProgress 
        context['projects'] = projects


        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct your goal here is to get all the posts related to the project object obtained from the current request. I will assume that your app `urls.py` include something like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
# ...
  path('projects/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectView.as_view())
]
```

Then `DetailView` does all the heavy lifting and you just need to do the following in your `views.py`

```py
class ProjectView(DetailView):
    model = MyProjects

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        current_project = self.get_object()  # Here's where the magic happens !
        completed = Post.objects.filter(status='Completed', project=current_project)
        inProgress = Post.objects.filter(status='InProgress', project=current_project)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(project= CurrentProject)
        features = Post.objects.filter(ticket_type='Features', project=current_project)

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = posts 
        context['Features'] = features 
        context['completed'] = completed 
        context['inProgress'] = inProgress 
        context['projects'] = projects

        return context
```

And thanks to some other django magic you could do even better

```py
class ProjectView(DetailView):
    model = MyProjects

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        current_project = self.get_object()  # Here's where the magic happens !
        posts = current_project.post_set.all()
        completed = posts.filter(status='Completed')
        inProgress = posts.filter(status='InProgress')
        features = posts.filter(ticket_type='Features')

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = posts 
        context['Features'] = features 
        context['completed'] = completed 
        context['inProgress'] = inProgress 
        context['projects'] = projects

        return context
```